# Prettier css allow custom words

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, prettier

I want prettier in vscode to allow variables with format `${variable}` both in selectors and in properties, so that the css file is formatted whether these variables are present or not.

Currently when I try to format the css document, that contains these variables, with prettier, it throws the following errors:

```
["ERROR" - 08:02:15] Error formatting document.
["ERROR" - 08:02:15] CssSyntaxError: Unknown word (4:11)
> 2 | ${variable}  {
    at i (/Users/user/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-10.1.0/node_modules/prettier/parser-postcss.js:1:13718)
    at ya (/Users/user/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-10.1.0/node_modules/prettier/parser-postcss.js:76:8108)
    at Tt (/Users/user/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-10.1.0/node_modules/prettier/parser-postcss.js:76:8665)
    at Object.mp [as parse] (/Users/user/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-10.1.0/node_modules/prettier/parser-postcss.js:76:8403)
    at Object.parse (/Users/user/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-10.1.0/node_modules/prettier/index.js:7515:23)
    at coreFormat (/Users/user/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-10.1.0/node_modules/prettier/index.js:8829:18)
    at formatWithCursor2 (/Users/user/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-10.1.0/node_modules/prettier/index.js:9021:18)
    at /Users/user/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-10.1.0/node_modules/prettier/index.js:38183:12
    at Object.format (/Users/user/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-10.1.0/node_modules/prettier/index.js:38197:12)
    at t.default.format (/Users/user/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-10.1.0/dist/extension.js:1:16114)
    at async t.PrettierEditProvider.provideEdits (/Users/user/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-10.1.0/dist/extension.js:1:12672)
    at async U.provideDocumentFormattingEdits (/private/var/folders/fp/txr11fws7zs_w6y1bm4zqyx40000gn/T/AppTranslocation/63BC26EF-CAF4-42B1-8ECE-A61827D0772F/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:104:44948)
```

Any idea?
Thank you.

Comment: what's the current behaviour that you observe? How can that behaviour be minimally reproduced ([mre])?

Comment: @starball I just updated the description with the current behaviour